# URLs appended with a fullstop (period)

Tags: web-hosting, url, analytics, website-design, ftp

When I log into to my hosting provider to view my website stats I have noticed that there are a few repeated page URLs with a full stop on the end. I have hunted for this additional page on my FTP but can't locate them anywhere. Ideally I want to remove these from my analytics because they will skew my stats. The pages I'm referring to are these ones.

/botanicals/homemade-gin-kit/1/.
/botanicals/homemade-gin-kit/3/.
/botanicals/homemade-gin-kit/2/.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: A period after a directory means "the current directory" in unix parlance.  With the full stop is just another way of accessing the index page in that directory.  Maybe users get to these URLs when they end a sentence with the URL and include a period.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly due to an incorrect link to your site from somewhere else.

Most forum software has bad auto-link detection so if someone posts a URL at the end of a sentence and finishes the sentence with a period, it will include the period in the URL link. The same thing often happens with URLs in parentheses.

In general there isn't anything you can do. But look at specific circumstances and add 301 redirects, especially if you are getting a lot of traffic to those non-existent URLs, e.g. redirect `example.com/1/.` to the real URL `example.com/1/`